# need help regarding submit event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to develop a form. Before submitting to server i validate it using jquery, everything is working fine except function on submit event, form is being submitted with errors, while checking in console window, error is like this, "unreachable code after return statement",please give some suggestions
Excerpt of html:

```
<form name="empform" action="editformProcess.php" method="POST" id="empform1"><a name="profileform1"></a>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 box"><label>First Name </label></div>
        <div class="col-md-7 boxinput"><span class="colenSpan">:&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="firstName" id="fName" required /></div>   
    </div>

    <div class="row ErrorMessg">
        <div class="col-md-5 "></div>
        <div class="col-md-7 " id="firstNameErrorMsg"> </div>   
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 box"><label>Last Name </label></div>
        <div class="col-md-7 boxinput"><span class="colenSpan">:&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="lastName" /></div>
    </div> 
    <div class="row">
        <h3>Contact Details </h3>
        <div class="col-md-5 box"><label>Email Id </label></div>
        <div class="col-md-7 boxinput"><span class="colenSpan">:&nbsp;</span><input type="email" name="emailId" required /></div>
    </div>  

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 box"><label>Mobile Number </label></div>
        <div class="col-md-7 boxinput"><span class="colenSpan">:&nbsp;</span><input type="text"  name="mobileNumber"  id= "mobNum" required /></div>
        <div id="mobbox"></div>
    </div>



    <div class="row ErrorMessg">
        <div class="col-md-5"><label></label></div>
        <div class="col-md-7" id="mobileNumMess"> </div>
        <div id="mobbox"></div>
    </div>

     <input type="submit" name="submitDetails" value="Submit Details" id="submit"/>

</form>
```

excerpt of jquery:

```
$(function(){
    //firstNameErrorMsg


    $("#firstNameErrorMsg").hide();
    $("#mobileNumMess").hide();

    var errorFirstName= false;
    var mobileNum= false;


    $("#fName").focusout(function(){
        checkFirstName();

    });

    $("#mobNum").focusout(function(){

        checkMobNum();

    });

    function checkFirstName(){
         var fNameLength = $("#fName").val().length;
         if(fNameLength < 5 || fNameLength > 20){
            $("#firstNameErrorMsg").html("sholud be between 5-20 charecters "); 
            $("#firstNameErrorMsg").show();
            errorFirstName= true;

         }else
         {
             $("#firstNameErrorMsg").hide();


         }


    }

    function checkMobNum(){
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/); 
        if(pattern.test($("#mobNum").val())){
            $("#mobileNumMess").hide();
        }else{
                $("#mobileNumMess").html("Invalid Mobile Number");
                $("#mobileNumMess").show();
                mobileNum = true;
                console.log("h from begin sub");

        }
    }

    $("#empform1").on('submit',function(){

        //return true;
        //console.log("h from begin2 sub1");
        var errorFirstName= false;
        var mobileNum= false;

        checkFirstName();
        checkMobNum();
        //console.log("under var");

        if(errorFirstName == false){
            return true;
            console.log("under if");
        }else{
            return false;
        }



    })
});
```

Comment: When I run your code I'm not able to reproduce the error you are speaking about.

Comment: whether form is being submitted, with errors

Comment: Can you explain what the submit problems / errors are, or is that a secret?

Comment: no its not any secret, main problem was jquery submit event was not working as intended, in spite of writing code properly  I was not getting the code working,later i came to know that variable declaration in submit event were creating problems, referring answer from dhbalaji, after making changes the code was working fine. @peterAbolins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct your code in 2 places.

1. To solve form submit issue, you need to remove the variable declaration inside submit method

   `$("#empform1").on('submit',function(){
       //return true;
       //console.log("h from begin2 sub1");
       //var errorFirstName= false;
       //var mobileNum= false;`
2. Dont forget to reset the var errorFirstName inside checkFirstName method

   ```
   } else {
   $("#firstNameErrorMsg").hide();
   errorFirstName = false;
   }]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

When an expression exists after a valid return statement, a warning is given to indicate that the code after the return statement is unreachable, meaning it can never be run. Here,

```
if(errorFirstName == false){
    return true;
    console.log("under if");
}
```

is the error. The string is being logged after the return statement. Change this to:

```
if(errorFirstName == false){
    console.log("under if");
    return true;
}
```

I hope this was should fix it, though I am not able to reproduce the error.

Referring to any problems with submit, here's how I would suggest you edit the code:

```
 function checkFirstName(){
     var fNameLength = $("#fName").val().length;
     if(fNameLength < 5 || fNameLength > 20){
        $("#firstNameErrorMsg").html("sholud be between 5-20 charecters "); 
        $("#firstNameErrorMsg").show();
        return true;
     }else
     {
         $("#firstNameErrorMsg").hide();
         return false
     }
}

function checkMobNum(){
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/); 
    if(pattern.test($("#mobNum").val())){
        $("#mobileNumMess").hide();
            return false;
    }else{
            $("#mobileNumMess").html("Invalid Mobile Number");
            $("#mobileNumMess").show();
            console.log("h from begin sub");
            return true;
    }
}

$("#empform1").on('submit',function(){
    var errorFirstName= checkFirstName();
    var mobileNum= checkMobNum();

    if(errorFirstName == false){
        return true;
        console.log("under if");
    }else{
        return false;
    }
})
```

What you apparently intended to do with the code was to modify the errorFirstName and mobileNum in the scope of the function (the event handler) according to the check functions. But it doesn't work that way.

When you changed the variables in the check functions, the global variable was referred first of all. That's not something I guess you had intended.

As a good practice, I suggest you return the test results, as I have in the edited code.

This problem could also be solved by removing the lines of code which declares local variables with the same name in the handler function.

Comment: actually, main problem is not for the console error , main problem is that of form submission, with errors,

Comment: @ShahbazKhan Make the edits I suggested, try it out and tell if it works.

Comment: error is not appearing ,but i think if condition is not being executed @shivenSinha

Comment: @ShahbazKhan No, these errors most of the time pop out while parsing the  code. It doesn't relate to whether the condition is being executed. Does it explain it? Check out the MDN link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Stmt_after_return

Comment: my problem for submit event is not solved by this solution, thanks for your suggestions @ShivenSinha